# AWS - Restrict access in a specific domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I would like to restrict a sub domain to be acessed only when inside company network.

We are using a VPN from AWS and we have configured other roles like VPC in EC2 that port 22 is only open for our network.

I’ve read about private hosted zone and restrict access by IP on S3 buckets where the static site is stored.

What is the right approach to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "restrict a sub domain to be accessed only when inside company network"? Do you mean the DNS name can only be resolved within the network? Or do you mean restrict access to some resource? What type of resource?

Comment: Hey @JohnRotenstein ! The DNS should be resolved within the network. I want to restrict access on S3 Bucket that is hosting a website. I've did it by setup a policy but it's not working when people is using VPN

Comment: Yes, you can create a Private Hosted Zone to resolve DNS only within the network. However, resources on the other side of the VPN might need to be modified to use the VPC's DNS server rather than the default VPC server. And, yes, you can create a Bucket Policy on the S3 bucket so that it is only accessible from a given range of IP addresses.